# Navbar image display properly in some views, but not others (Laravel PHP webapp)

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm using Laravel to create a simple webapp, based on template code.

The Navbar in `resources/views/master/navbar.blade.php` has a section that's always present intended for the site name and icon, then adds other links depending on the user role and view.

On the pre-logged in "home" ("`login`") view, the icon and text display as expected. However, once logged in it seems the text displays in all views but the image becomes broken in others. The image resides in the `public` folder on the server. Not sure why this happens, or how to fix it?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{route('home')}}">{{env('APP_NAME')}}</a>
      <img src="icon.png" alt="Site Icon" width="50" height="50">
      Site Name
    </div>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
      @if(Auth::check())
       <li><a href="{{route('home')}}">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</spa>
        @if(Auth::user()->admin == true)
          <li><a href="{{route('admin')}}">AP</a></li>
        @endif
 ...
```

Comment: wait why is it on the master folder i think it should be on the views folder

Comment: If the image is located in root of your web folder just add `/` at the begging. Like this: `<img src="/icon.png"...`

Comment: @xAtifx You may be right, but that's where I found the navbar PHP file in the template

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco That was it! Thank you!

Comment: @laravellava You are very welcome :)